# SQL Date conversion getting "Invalid Number"

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

Hello I have the following date in SQL ORCLE

```
2020-02-07 13:21:56.478000
```

And I want it in the following format:

```
27-JAN-20 03.00.00.000000000 AM
```

I googled around and found the to_char and to_date and came up with this

```
(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR('2020-02-07 13:21:56.478000','DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS.FF'))
```

But I keep getting "invalid number" and oracle is not telling me where it is. Any ideas?

Comment: `to_char` takes something that is not already a character string, like  date or a number, and converts it in**to** a **char**acter string. It doesn't make sense to `to_char` a character string. It would be like using `to_number` on a number, or `to_date` on a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following method

```
to_char(
    timestamp '2020-02-07 13:21:56.478000',
    'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS.FF'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `to_char()` expects a date-like datatype as argument, while your are giving it a string.

If you are dealing with a literal string, then you use the date literal syntax:

```
to_char(
    timestamp '2020-02-07 13:21:56.478000',
    'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS.FF AM'
)
```

If you are dealing with a string column, then you can turn it to a timestamp first with `to_timestamp()`:

```
to_char(
    to_timestamp(my_string_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
    'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS.FF AM'
)
```

Finally, if you are dealing with a `timestamp` column, then you can use `to_char()` directly:

```
to_char(my_date_col, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS.FF AM')
```

Note: your original format modifier was missing the `AM/PM` part, I added it.